# Screenshoting isn't capturing what's on the screen

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, screenshot, win32gui, pyautogui

I'm trying to automatically take screenshots but depending on how things are navigated, I don't always capture what's actually on the screen.

As an exercise in ML I'm trying to write a bot to play a racing game, and while playing it's supposed to take screenshots and record telemetry every second or so. I'm using `pynput` to navigate the GUIs and `pyvjoy` to control the car. The game has a menu screen where you select the car and track and then click to start the event. At that point the menu screen changes to a loading screen and over the loading screen another process and window opens in which the race happens. Hitting Alt+Tab shows the two separate windows and the Task Manager shows the 2 processes.

When I just had the bot starting, failing, and restarting the race once I had navigated to the event window, without ever leaving the event window, it was properly saving screenshots. But once I changed it so that it'd start at the menu screen, pick a track, "race" a few times, exit the event back to the menu screen, pick the next track, and so on, instead of getting screenshots of the race, it takes screenshots of the menu's loading screen even though it isn't visible on screen.

This was the basic code, using `PIL`, that was working in the first incarnation of the bot but not the track selecting one.

```
image = np.array(ImageGrab.grab())
im = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY))
im.save(str(time.time()) + '.png')
```

Then I tried `pyautogui` but still got the same behavior

```
image = np.array(pyautogui.screenshot())
im = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY))
im.save(str(time.time()) + '.png')
```

I tried to emulating a keyboard key press to capture a screenshot and then use that but I got that there were no images in the clipboard.

```
import pynput.keyboard as kbd
import pynput.mouse as mus

keyboard = kbd.Controller()
mouse = mus.Controller()

keyboard.press(kbd.Key.print_screen)
time.sleep(0.01)
keyboard.release(kbd.Key.print_screen)
image = np.array(ImageGrab.grabclipboard())
im = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY))
im.save(str(time.time()) + '.png')
```

I noticed that if I used Alt+Tab to move around between windows during a run it would start to work so I used `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(win32gui.FindWindow('acsw', None))` to make the window I cared about the active window in combination with other previously attempted screen capturing code but still nothing. I also used win32gui on its own and got the same results as with everything else.

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow('acsw', None)
dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmapFromHandle()
w=1920
h=1080
dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, w, h)
cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
cDC.BitBlt((0,0),(w, h) , dcObj, (0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, str(time.time())+'.bmp')
# Free Resources
dcObj.DeleteDC()
cDC.DeleteDC()
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
```

I also tried using `pynput` to click on the window that I was trying to capture, once it was visible to ensure that it was active, but this too didn't work.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to screenshot the active window?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a video to see the behavior in real time?